# Difference between PLS_INTEGER and INTEGER for below scenario

Tags: oracle, plsql, casting, oracle11g, type-conversion

Please see these two scenarios :

**Case 1:**

```
DECLARE
p1 PLS_INTEGER := 2147483647;
p2 INTEGER := 1;
n NUMBER;
BEGIN
n := p1 + p2;
END;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

**Case 2**

```
DECLARE
p1 PLS_INTEGER := 2147483647;
p2 PLS_INTEGER := 1;
n NUMBER;
BEGIN
n := p1 + p2;
END;

Error at line 1
ORA-01426: numeric overflow
ORA-06512: at line 6
```

Why does `case 2` failed, even I was trying to add same data type whereas `case 1` executes successfully ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation for [PLS_INTEGER and BINARY_INTEGER Data Types](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/datatypes.htm#LNPLS99938)
only says:

> A calculation with two PLS_INTEGER values that overflows the PLS_INTEGER range raises an overflow exception, even if you assign the result to a NUMBER data type.

But it does not tell you why.I assume the reason is PLS_INTEGER operations use hardware arithmetic, so Oracle properly does it internally like

```
n := CAST(p1 + p2 AS NUMBER);
```

Answer (score 0):

PLS_INTEGER is a PL/SQL data type which, according to [the PL/SQL Language Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/datatypes.htm#LNPLS319):

> stores signed integers in the range -2,147,483,648 through 2,147,483,647

On the other hand, INTEGER is an ANSI SQL Data Type which Oracle converts into a NUMBER with zero scale.

According to the [Database SQL Language Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF30020), NUMBER is an Oracle Built-in Data Type which

> stores zero as well as positive and negative fixed numbers with absolute values from 1.0 x 10^-130 to but not including 1.0 x 10^126

Answer (score 0):

PLS_INTEGER can store upto 2,147,483,647. Crossing this, would result in overflow exception.

INTEGER is a predefined subtype of the NUMBER data type, and is usually referred as NUMBER(38). That means, it can go upto (10^39) - 1. So, no exception your first code block.